# How to remove the repeating column headers in List box style view with more than 2 boxes on a row with alternating line style?

Tags: 2013, list, 2016

I have a requirement to group list items by Platform and environment. Then a box style to view the list items with alternating line style and only one column header and the data that is common in all the boxes to display at the bottom of the list only once.